# Problema de recorrencia prolog

Tags: recursão, prolog

Como resolver isto? Eu estou a tentar fazer um programa que receba um caminho e traduz em direcoes a seguir (cima(0),direita(90),esquerda(270),baixo(180)). O predicado `vizinha` da a `Dir` uma das direcoes(0,90,180,270) , exemplo:     `test([ (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6), (6, 7), (7, 7)],L).` devia dar `L=[0,90,0,90]`, mas da `L=[0]`. Fiz trace e esta ai o link da imagem [O trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxo5hF15vtsLbXQ4dXhFVmg4bUE/view?usp=sharing)

```
test([(_,_)],_).

test([A|P],List):-
    B=(_,_),
    append([B],_,P),     
    vizinha(A,B,Dir), 
    append(List,[Dir],List1), 
    test(P,List1).
```

Comment: Hello, this is the Portguese Stackoverflow, for questions in english please, go to the http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Seu segundo `append` está com os argumentos na ordem errada. Lembre-se que o valor de saída de `test` é `List`, então `List` é que tem que começar com `Dir` e terminar com o resultado da recursão:

```
append([Dir], List1, List),
```

Além disso, seu caso base está retornando "qualquer coisa" caso a entrada só tenha um elemento - o ideal seria retornar a lista vazia, pois do contrário vão existir infinitos resultados:

```
test([(_,_)], []).
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/8V8H26)